# Errore Package SpalshScreen.Fody

Tags: c, fody

**English Translation :**

I installed the `SplashScreen.Fody` Package in the VisualStudio environment for my project, the user guide was to add a WPF UserControl to the project that generated a .xaml file for creating and managing a SplashScreen. Only then did I opt for another option and decided to delete the .xaml file from the project and its package. Now, however, I get this error when launching the application and I can't understand why it happens even after removing the file and the package.

How can I solve it?

**Original Post :**

Ho installato il [Package SplashScreen.Fody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJUsF.png) nell'ambiente VisualStudio per un mio progetto, la guida all'uso prevedeva di aggiungere un UserControl WPF al progetto che  generava un file .xaml per la creazione e gestione di un SplashScreen. Solo dopo ho optato per una altra opzione e ho deciso di eliminare il file .xaml dal progetto e il relativo package. Ora però ricevo questo errore al lancio dell'applicazzione e non riesco a capire perche succede anche dopo aver rimosso il file e il package. Come posso Risolvere?

Comment: L'errore è questo : Fody/SplashScreen: No single class with the [SplashScreen] 
                    attribute found: La sequenza non contiene elementi corrispondenti

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it English only site

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tom-englert/SplashScreen.Fody#how-to-use

> To have a dynamically designable splash screen in your application, simply add a WPF UserControl to your applications assembly, design it, and apply the [SplashScreen] attribute to it:

you are probably missing something like this

```
[SplashScreen(MinimumVisibilityDuration = 4, FadeoutDuration = 1)]
public partial class MySplashScreen
{
    public MySplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the file version info.
    /// </summary>
    public FileVersionInfo FileVersionInfo { get; } = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
```